# Vuejs shows a vague stack trace

Tags: vue.js, webpack, source-maps

I get at the begin when my website loads a vague stack trace. I'm using the default settings which enables source-map for development.

The stack trace i get:

[image]

Errors that occur after this do show up normally..
Anyone has an idea why this happens and how to fix it?

Thank you